# Process started by subprocess seems to be sleeping. Why?

Tags: python, process, subprocess, python-multithreading, mplayer

Though this is a very specific puzzler I guess the problem presented here is of a more general nature.

What I am trying to do is to build a simple media player for fun and learning. I'm trying to do this using https://github.com/n1ck3/mplayer.py which spawns *mplayer* and commands the *mplayer* instance to play some audio file.

For a start I have build a test program on an older system which looks basically like this:

```
player = Player()
player.loadfile(SOUND_FILE)

while (player.time_pos is not None):
    print(player.time_pos)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This works perfectly on the old system with python 3.4. Now I switched to a system running python 3.5 on the most recent Ubuntu and it strangely does not work any more.

I tracked down the problem as far as I could. On my old system the loop will properly sleep for one second and the *mplayer* subprocess will run in the background as expected. On the new system the *mplayer* subprocess will only run for that fraction of a second the query `player.time_pos` will take to execute. Then the subprocess will sleep and not run in the background any more until it is queried again by `player.time_pos`.

This can be tracked down by watching the output of `print(player.time_pos)`: On the old system the output numbers will increase rapidly every second as expected, but on the new system they will only grow very, very, very slowly. If I remove the `sleep` statement I can hear sound, but it is a bit slowed down and very noisy due to lot's of small interruptions.

I had a look at the implementation of the *mplayer* module. It internally uses `subprocess` and connects via pipes to the *mplayer* process spawned:

```
self._proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=self._stdout._handle, stderr=self._stderr._handle,
    fsize=16384, close_fds=(sys.platform != 'win32'))
```

*Note: I experimented with `fsize` here but it had no effect.*

Has something changed from python 3.4 to 3.5 I am not aware of? Are there some more options required now in order to get the *mplayer* process running in the background? I haven't worked with `subprocess` yet so do you have some information for me why this does not work as expected?

Comment: you should get `TypeError` due to `fsize`. You might mean `bufsize` instead. Do not type the code by hand, copy-paste it as is.

Comment: As far as I can tell the code was written to work on Python 2 where `bufsize=0` by default and no short reads/writes. The recent updates for py3 might have missed something. Install Python 3.4 on your new system and make sure that if it works then submit the bug report.